# What's the difference between endDialog() and endConversion() in Bot-Framework (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am confused with `endDialog()` and `endConversion()` when using bot-framework.

What's the difference between them?

[image]

[image]

If I don't invoke them, just using `send()`? What constraint will be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inside a dialog, you can invoke some other dialog. For e.g.

```
   bot.dialog("/", [
    function(session, data, next()){
        session.send("Hi");
        if(session.message.text === "hello"){
            // starts a new dialog
            session.beginDialog("helloDialog");
            next();
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }, function(sesion, data){
        session.send("end of root dialog");
    }
]);

bot.dialog("helloDialog",[
    function(session){
        session.send("inside the hello dialog");
        session.endDialog(); // explicitly ends the dialog
    }
])
```

When user input is **hello**, output is

- Hi
- inside the hello dialog
- end of root dialog

When user input is anything else, output is

- Hi
- end of root dialog

`session.endDialog` ends the current dialog, and resumes the parent dialog.
`session.endConversation` ends the conversation itself.

In Technical terms, when a dialog is called, the dialog moves into a stack called dialogStack. When another dialog is called from current dialog, that new dialog is placed at the top of dialogStack. When this new dialog completes its operation, this dialog is popped from the stack, and the last dialog resumes.

When `session.endConversation` is invoked, the dialog stack is emptied right away (this is a behavior am not fully sure though)

Comment: If I replace `endDialog()` with `endConversion()` in your example, output is `Hi` --> `inside the hello dialog`. There is not `end of root dialog`, is it true?

Comment: Yes. Although I haven't tested (cannot test right now), but I just checked the source of `session.endConversation` it does clears the dialog stack. So there should be no `end of root dialog`.